# understanding SUB used in an AWK command

Tags: awk, substitution

I need to understand how this command is working:

```
awk 'BEGIN{while(a++<30)s=s " "};{sub(/^.{6}/,"&" s)};l' myfile
```

I understand how the first part (the expression in the BEGIN{} section) creates a 30 character long string of spaces. But don't understand the second part (sub).

The `sub` adds the recently generated string "s" to the 6th column of 'myfile'. But the way I see the command, the search pattern `/^.{6}/` should look for all lines that start with one character (.) and then {6} and replace those with space-added string!

Can you please help me to understand this better?

Comment: Get rid of the null statements (spurious semi-colons) and that should ba a number one (`1`) at the end of the script, not the letter el (`l`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the 6th column, and it's not looking for a literal {6}.

The curly braces mean "this many of the preceding pattern" (if you invoke GNU awk with --posix or --re-interval).

So this pattern:

```
/^.{6}/
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
/^....../
```

What it's doing is adding the string `s` after the first 6 characters, which may be any characters.

The following awk command would do something similar:

```
awk 'BEGIN{while(a++<30)s=s " "} {print substr($0, 1, 6) s substr($0, 7)}' myfile
```

Comment: RE-intervals are enabled by default in recent gawk distributions so you only need --re-interval if you have an older version of gawk (and you should avoid --posix).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comprehensive reply! It was really helpful.

Comment: @EdMorton thanks for the tip, I'm using GNU awk 3.1.7 on CentoS 6.4, and I had to use the flag.  What counts as a recent gawk distribution that enables it by default?

Comment: It's enabled by default in gawk 4.0.0, not sure about before that. gawk's up to release 4.1.0 now.

Comment: Aha, thanks.  The enterprise Linux distros tend to be slow to update some packages.

Comment: Sorry if this question sounds too simple. But I thought awk is just a symbolic link to gawk. So why there is the need to specify gawk in the above command? 
Also, I tried  to run the code (with gawk) in my OSX terminal (in -bash mode) but it could not be found.

Comment: @user2395215, OS X is based on FreeBSD UNIX, and I believe it uses UNIX implementations of most tools, not GNU tools.

Answer (score 2):

See @BillKarwin's answer for what it's doing, and see the 2nd awk script below for the more concise way to do it:

```
$ cat file
abcdefghi

$ awk 'BEGIN{while(a++<30)s=s " "} {sub(/^.{6}/,"&" s)} 1' file
abcdef                              ghi

$ awk '{printf "%-36s%s\n",substr($0,1,6),substr($0,7)}' file
abcdef                              ghi
```